# Error trying to run pySpark on my own machine

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I want to experiment with running Spark on my own Mac (version 10.11.6). I downloaded Spark 2.0.0 and then tried to run ./bin/pyspark.

However, I'm getting the following errors:

```
Python 2.7.12 |Anaconda custom (x86_64)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:43:17) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel).
16/09/13 15:27:47 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/09/13 15:27:47 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.net.UnknownHostException: huey: huey: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1473)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.findLocalInetAddress(Utils.scala:846)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.org$apache$spark$util$Utils$$localIpAddress$lzycompute(Utils.scala:839)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.org$apache$spark$util$Utils$$localIpAddress(Utils.scala:839)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$localHostName$1.apply(Utils.scala:896)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$localHostName$1.apply(Utils.scala:896)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.localHostName(Utils.scala:896)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:388)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:240)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:236)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:211)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: huey: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:901)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1293)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1469)
    ... 20 more
16/09/13 15:27:47 WARN SparkContext: Another SparkContext is being constructed (or threw an exception in its constructor).  This may indicate an error, since only one SparkContext may be running in this JVM (see SPARK-2243). The other SparkContext was created at:
org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:240)
py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:236)
py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:211)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/09/13 15:27:47 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.net.UnknownHostException: huey: huey: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1473)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.findLocalInetAddress(Utils.scala:846)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.org$apache$spark$util$Utils$$localIpAddress$lzycompute(Utils.scala:839)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.org$apache$spark$util$Utils$$localIpAddress(Utils.scala:839)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$localHostName$1.apply(Utils.scala:896)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$localHostName$1.apply(Utils.scala:896)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.localHostName(Utils.scala:896)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:388)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:240)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:236)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:211)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: huey: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:901)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1293)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1469)
    ... 20 more
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hkwik/Downloads/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/shell.py", line 47, in <module>
    spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
  File "/Users/hkwik/Downloads/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 169, in getOrCreate
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
  File "/Users/hkwik/Downloads/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/context.py", line 294, in getOrCreate
    SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
  File "/Users/hkwik/Downloads/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/context.py", line 115, in __init__
    conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
  File "/Users/hkwik/Downloads/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/context.py", line 168, in _do_init
    self._jsc = jsc or self._initialize_context(self._conf._jconf)
  File "/Users/hkwik/Downloads/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/context.py", line 233, in _initialize_context
    return self._jvm.JavaSparkContext(jconf)
  File "/Users/hkwik/Downloads/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1183, in __call__
  File "/Users/hkwik/Downloads/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 312, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.net.UnknownHostException: huey: huey: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1473)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.findLocalInetAddress(Utils.scala:846)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.org$apache$spark$util$Utils$$localIpAddress$lzycompute(Utils.scala:839)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.org$apache$spark$util$Utils$$localIpAddress(Utils.scala:839)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$localHostName$1.apply(Utils.scala:896)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$localHostName$1.apply(Utils.scala:896)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.localHostName(Utils.scala:896)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:388)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:240)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:236)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:211)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: huey: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:901)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1293)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1469)
    ... 20 more
```

I tried setting SPARK_LOCAL_IP to localhost to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: You can also easily install Apache Spark by using Homebrew. Just run `brew install apache-spark`. See http://brewformulas.org/ApacheSpark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like adding a line to /etc/hosts mapping 127.0.0.1 to huey fixes the issue.

Comment: can you explain further? What is "huey"?